# How to get the system info with Python?

Tags: python, system-information

I need to get the info under what environment the software is running. 
Does python have a library for this purpose?

I want to know the following info.

- OS name/version
- Name of the CPU, clock speed
- Number of CPU core
- Size of memory

Comment: All I got is os.name from here: http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#miscellaneous-system-information

Comment: From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python), psutil: http://code.google.com/p/psutil/

Answer (score 122, accepted):

some of these could be obtained from the [`platform`](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html) module:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.machine()
'x86'
>>> platform.version()
'5.1.2600'
>>> platform.platform()
'Windows-XP-5.1.2600-SP2'
>>> platform.uname()
('Windows', 'name', 'XP', '5.1.2600', 'x86', 'x86 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 6, GenuineIntel')
>>> platform.system()
'Windows'
>>> platform.processor()
'x86 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 6, GenuineIntel'
```

Comment: You beat me.  Also, I don't know about other OS's, but on Unix it may be better to run platform.dist() as it's more concise.

Comment: platform.dist() is deprecated in Python 3.5

Comment: [`platform.dist()` was removed in Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/platform.html#platform.dist).

Comment: Good thing we got this. It was sorely missing.

Comment: Thanks. What about RAM. Is that possible to find out?

Answer (score 45):

```
#Shamelessly combined from google and other stackoverflow like sites to form a single function

import platform,socket,re,uuid,json,psutil,logging

def getSystemInfo():
    try:
        info={}
        info['platform']=platform.system()
        info['platform-release']=platform.release()
        info['platform-version']=platform.version()
        info['architecture']=platform.machine()
        info['hostname']=socket.gethostname()
        info['ip-address']=socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        info['mac-address']=':'.join(re.findall('..', '%012x' % uuid.getnode()))
        info['processor']=platform.processor()
        info['ram']=str(round(psutil.virtual_memory().total / (1024.0 **3)))+" GB"
        return json.dumps(info)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)

json.loads(getSystemInfo())
```

---

Output Sample:

```
{
 'platform': 'Linux',
 'platform-release': '5.3.0-29-generic',
 'platform-version': '#31-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 17 17:27:26 UTC 2020',
 'architecture': 'x86_64',
 'hostname': 'naret-vm',
 'ip-address': '127.0.1.1',
 'mac-address': 'bb:cc:dd:ee:bc:ff',
 'processor': 'x86_64',
 'ram': '4 GB'
}
```

Comment: To get the GPU Name in Windows, 
`import wmi # pip install wmi`
`computer = wmi.WMI()`
`gpu_info = computer.Win32_VideoController()[0].name`

Comment: out of context comment. ```can we please don't use Java naming style in python. like the function name in the answer.  get_system_info() is more pythonic than java camelcase method naming```

Answer (score 14):

The [os module](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) has the uname function to get information about the os & version:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.uname()
```

For my system, running CentOS 5.4 with 2.6.18 kernel this returns:

> ('Linux', 'mycomputer.domain.user','2.6.18-92.1.22.el5PAE', '#1 SMP Tue
>   Dec 16 12:36:25 EST 2008', 'i686')

Comment: Note: This only works on *nix. From official doc: "Availability: recent flavors of Unix."

Comment: Note: This also works on ProductName:    `Mac OS X` | ProductVersion: 10.14.2 | BuildVersion:   18C54

Answer (score 9):

```
import psutil
import platform
from datetime import datetime
import cpuinfo
import socket
import uuid
import re


def get_size(bytes, suffix="B"):
    """
    Scale bytes to its proper format
    e.g:
        1253656 => '1.20MB'
        1253656678 => '1.17GB'
    """
    factor = 1024
    for unit in ["", "K", "M", "G", "T", "P"]:
        if bytes < factor:
            return f"{bytes:.2f}{unit}{suffix}"
        bytes /= factor

def System_information():
    print("="*40, "System Information", "="*40)
    uname = platform.uname()
    print(f"System: {uname.system}")
    print(f"Node Name: {uname.node}")
    print(f"Release: {uname.release}")
    print(f"Version: {uname.version}")
    print(f"Machine: {uname.machine}")
    print(f"Processor: {uname.processor}")
    print(f"Processor: {cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()['brand_raw']}")
    print(f"Ip-Address: {socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())}")
    print(f"Mac-Address: {':'.join(re.findall('..', '%012x' % uuid.getnode()))}")


    # Boot Time
    print("="*40, "Boot Time", "="*40)
    boot_time_timestamp = psutil.boot_time()
    bt = datetime.fromtimestamp(boot_time_timestamp)
    print(f"Boot Time: {bt.year}/{bt.month}/{bt.day} {bt.hour}:{bt.minute}:{bt.second}")


    # print CPU information
    print("="*40, "CPU Info", "="*40)
    # number of cores
    print("Physical cores:", psutil.cpu_count(logical=False))
    print("Total cores:", psutil.cpu_count(logical=True))
    # CPU frequencies
    cpufreq = psutil.cpu_freq()
    print(f"Max Frequency: {cpufreq.max:.2f}Mhz")
    print(f"Min Frequency: {cpufreq.min:.2f}Mhz")
    print(f"Current Frequency: {cpufreq.current:.2f}Mhz")
    # CPU usage
    print("CPU Usage Per Core:")
    for i, percentage in enumerate(psutil.cpu_percent(percpu=True, interval=1)):
        print(f"Core {i}: {percentage}%")
    print(f"Total CPU Usage: {psutil.cpu_percent()}%")


    # Memory Information
    print("="*40, "Memory Information", "="*40)
    # get the memory details
    svmem = psutil.virtual_memory()
    print(f"Total: {get_size(svmem.total)}")
    print(f"Available: {get_size(svmem.available)}")
    print(f"Used: {get_size(svmem.used)}")
    print(f"Percentage: {svmem.percent}%")



    print("="*20, "SWAP", "="*20)
    # get the swap memory details (if exists)
    swap = psutil.swap_memory()
    print(f"Total: {get_size(swap.total)}")
    print(f"Free: {get_size(swap.free)}")
    print(f"Used: {get_size(swap.used)}")
    print(f"Percentage: {swap.percent}%")



    # Disk Information
    print("="*40, "Disk Information", "="*40)
    print("Partitions and Usage:")
    # get all disk partitions
    partitions = psutil.disk_partitions()
    for partition in partitions:
        print(f"=== Device: {partition.device} ===")
        print(f"  Mountpoint: {partition.mountpoint}")
        print(f"  File system type: {partition.fstype}")
        try:
            partition_usage = psutil.disk_usage(partition.mountpoint)
        except PermissionError:
            # this can be catched due to the disk that
            # isn't ready
            continue
        print(f"  Total Size: {get_size(partition_usage.total)}")
        print(f"  Used: {get_size(partition_usage.used)}")
        print(f"  Free: {get_size(partition_usage.free)}")
        print(f"  Percentage: {partition_usage.percent}%")
    # get IO statistics since boot
    disk_io = psutil.disk_io_counters()
    print(f"Total read: {get_size(disk_io.read_bytes)}")
    print(f"Total write: {get_size(disk_io.write_bytes)}")

    ## Network information
    print("="*40, "Network Information", "="*40)
    ## get all network interfaces (virtual and physical)
    if_addrs = psutil.net_if_addrs()
    for interface_name, interface_addresses in if_addrs.items():
        for address in interface_addresses:
            print(f"=== Interface: {interface_name} ===")
            if str(address.family) == 'AddressFamily.AF_INET':
                print(f"  IP Address: {address.address}")
                print(f"  Netmask: {address.netmask}")
                print(f"  Broadcast IP: {address.broadcast}")
            elif str(address.family) == 'AddressFamily.AF_PACKET':
                print(f"  MAC Address: {address.address}")
                print(f"  Netmask: {address.netmask}")
                print(f"  Broadcast MAC: {address.broadcast}")
    ##get IO statistics since boot
    net_io = psutil.net_io_counters()
    print(f"Total Bytes Sent: {get_size(net_io.bytes_sent)}")
    print(f"Total Bytes Received: {get_size(net_io.bytes_recv)}")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    System_information()
```

Answer (score 4):

Found this Simple code

```
import platform

print("="*40, "System Information", "="*40)
uname = platform.uname()
print(f"System: {uname.system}")
print(f"Node Name: {uname.node}")
print(f"Release: {uname.release}")
print(f"Version: {uname.version}")
print(f"Machine: {uname.machine}")
print(f"Processor: {uname.processor}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#This should work

import os
for item in os.environ:

    print(f'{item}{" : "}{os.environ[item]}')
```