# get windows edition in any language

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to find out which edition of windows is installed on some users computers. 
I tried:

```
wmic os get Caption /value
```

and

```
systeminfo | find "OS Name
```

and

```
winver
```

The problem is that for different os languages I get the edition name also in that language, and I can't support all languages.
Does anybody know some useful way to find which edition the user has without being dependent on the language?

(the commands I used so far are meant for cmd, but I'm writing my program in python, so a solution for python is also ok)

thank you!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the system info with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103178/how-to-get-the-system-info-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.version()
'#46-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 2 13:38:30 UTC 2018'
>>> platform.machine()
'x86_64'
>>> platform.platform()
'Linux-4.13.0-41-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-17.10-artful'
>>> platform.uname()
uname_result(system='Linux', node='aniruddha088', release='4.13.0-41-generic', version='#46-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 2 13:38:30 UTC 2018', machine='x86_64', processor='x86_64')
>>> platform.system()
'Linux'
>>> platform.processor()
'x86_64'
```

Comment: thank you! I finally discovered this: wmic os get 'OperatingSystemSKU /value', it gives me a number instead of text, which solved my problem

Comment: Great! I thought I could be of some help.