# Check linux distribution from python

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to create a python script that runs on Linux, but in my script I want to check on which linux distribution it's running.

I found this code:

```
import platform
print(platform.linux_distribution())
```

but this returns: ('Ubuntu', '18.04', 'bionic')
And all I need to check is if it's Ubuntu / centOS... (doesn't matter which version)
How can I grep the first value and do a 'if' on it?

Comment: have you tried `platform.linux_distribution()[0]` already?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the system info with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103178/how-to-get-the-system-info-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

The return value is a `tuple` , you can use the index to fetch the desired value

```
from platform import linux_distribution

dist_tup = linux_distribution()

if dist_tup[0] == "Ubuntu":
   ##### Do Something
else:
   ##### Do something else
```