# How can I make a Tkinter application utilise all screen space?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to find a way to make a Tkinter application's main window utilise all screen space. I have to always maximise the screen after the app starts. I have tried this code:

```
win.state('zoomed')
```

However, it's not supported on Linux. I need a solution that will work on any platform.

Comment: Have you tried using the `wm_attributes` method?

Comment: @BryanOakley can you give me an example?

Comment: Try `win.wm_attributes('-zoom', 1)` as said by Bryan.

Comment: @acw1668 nothing happens.

Answer (score 3):

There's lots of information in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15981000/16775594), but there are issues on different systems with each:

- [`root.state("zoomed")`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22482930/16775594) doesn't work on Linux, but it does work on Windows.
- [`root.wm_attributes("-zoomed", True)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22275334/16775594) works in Linux (and Mac, as far as I know), but not in Windows.
- If you read the comments on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15982406/16775594), it appears it doesn't work well on all systems/on multiple monitors.

Basically, there doesn't appear to be any single cross-platform solution to this. So what I suggest is that you use a `try`/`except` block, and if one solution fails, use the other:

```py
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
try:
    root.wm_attributes("-zoomed", True)
except tkinter.TclError:
    root.state('zoomed')
root.mainloop()
```

An alternative for those who don't like `try`/`except` blocks is to use the built-in [`platform`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3103224/16775594) module, and some `if` statements:

```py
import tkinter, platform

root = tkinter.Tk()
if platform.uname()[0] == "Windows":
    root.state('zoomed')
else:
    root.wm_attributes("-zoomed", True)
root.mainloop()
```

I'm 99% sure this works on Windows, but as I don't have access to a Windows for testing, it'd be nice to have have someone confirm that it works on Windows. Hope this helps, and let me know if you have any questions!