# Animation in WXpython leads to "python.exe has stopped working"

Tags: python, animation, crash, wxpython

Below is the code from a work-in-progress script that I am writing. When the script is run I get a "python.exe is stopped working" pop-up. I have managed to locate the problem down to the animation which I have included. By removing the following line the program doesn't crash...

```
self.anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, init_func = self.anim_init, frames = int(100/self.freq), interval = 20, blit = True)
```

How would I go about including animation without causing python to crash? Am I missing something that needs to be included?

```
import wx, sys
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg  as FigureCanvas

class Waveform(wx.Panel):
    """Template of the animation waveform in a panel"""
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Waveform, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ud = 4    # Maximum voltage
        self.num_mod = 4.0    # Number of submodules
        self.freq = 1    # Frequency of the switching (Hz)

        self.fig = plt.figure()    # Create a waveform figure
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)    # Split the figure into subplots (1x1 grid, first plot)

        self.ax.set_xlim(0, 1)    # Define the scale of the x axis
        self.ax.set_ylim(0, self.ud + 0.8)    # Define the scale of the y axis

        self.ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)    # Hide axis

        self.ax.text(-0.10, self.ud, r'$U_d$')    # Add the label for the ud reference line
        self.ax.axhline(y = self.ud, color = 'black', linestyle = '--')    # Add the ud reference line

        self.ax.set_ylabel('$Voltage$')    # Label the y Axis
        self.ax.set_title(r'Upper Valve Voltage')    # Add the title to the subplot

        self.upper_value, = self.ax.plot([], [], label=r'Upper Total', linewidth = '2') 
        self.upper_value.set_data([], []) 

        self.canv = FigureCanvas(self, wx.ID_ANY, self.fig)

        self.anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, init_func = self.anim_init, frames = int(100/self.freq), interval = 20, blit = True) # Divide by frequency to ensure smooth animation

    def anim_init(self):
        self.upper_value.set_data([], [])
        return self.upper_value,

    def animate(self, i):
        x = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
        amplitude = self.ud/self.num_mod

        y = amplitude * signal.square(2 * np.pi * self.freq * (x + 0.01 * i)) + self.ud
        for num in range(1, int(self.num_mod)):
            phase = np.pi/self.num_mod * num
            z = amplitude * signal.square(2 * np.pi * self.freq * (x + 0.01 * i) + phase)
            y = y + z

        self.upper_value.set_data(x, y/2)
        return self.upper_value,

class Window(wx.Frame):
    """Template of the top-level (parent) widget called Frame"""
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        c_x, c_y, c_w, c_h = wx.ClientDisplayRect() # Finds the size of the screen (Removing the Taskbar)
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent, pos=(c_x, c_y), size=(c_w, c_h), title=title, style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX)

def main():

    app = wx.App(False)    # Create a new instance of a wxpython app (don't redirect stdout/stderr)
    frame = Window(None, title='Multi-level Converter Animation')    # Create a new frame object
    panel = Waveform(frame) # Create an instance of the waveform panel
    frame.Show()      # Display the complete window
    app.MainLoop()    # Enter a endless cycle that handles the events of the application

# Command-line interface.     
import os, argparse

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Included to allow realtime output to the console
    # Re-opens stdout file descriptor with write mode and 0 as the buffer size (unbuffered)
    sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0) 

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Animation of a Multilevel Converter')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    main()
```

Comment: Are you intending to return a tuple from your functions (`return self.upper_value,`)?

Comment: @SiHa Yes, I know it is not very pythonic as the functions should manipulate a self variable but animation.FuncAnimation() requires an initial function.

Comment: The usual suspects would be _insufficient memory_ or _insufficient disk space_.

Comment: @boardrider Interesting...How would I go about diagnosing this? How much memory/ disk space is required.

Comment: Profiling (http://www.huyng.com/posts/python-performance-analysis/), or calling a function you'd create from strategic places in your code. This function will display current free memory/disk (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260116/find-size-and-free-space-of-the-filesystem-containing-a-given-file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615591/available-and-used-system-memory-in-python).