# PC ram size using python or windows command line

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get current CPU and RAM usage in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python)

How to read pc ram size using python or wmi generator/Windows command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out psutil, Just a note to those using linux if you install this via a package manager just be aware of the version you are using as they are generally out of date.

> https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil
>
> psutil is a module providing an interface for retrieving information
>   on all running processes and system utilization (CPU, memory, disks,
>   network, users) in a portable way by using Python, implementing many
>   functionalities offered by command line tools such as:

For memory specifics check out http://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation#Memory