# How to find CPU utilization and memory usage after running a python script

Tags: python, memory, cpu-usage

I am working in python, I had a python script that reads the data from text file and saves in to database.

I got some requirement like to find below 3 points

```
1. Total execution time taken by the script for running
2. CPU utilization (For process performing by the python script)
3. Memory usage (For process performing by the python script)
```

For the first point i.e., i am finding the total execution time taken by the script to process(read the text file and saving in to database) as below

```
python -m cProfile script_that_runs_process.py
```

But i am unable to understand how to find the another two points ? 
I googled and found some python module [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) , but i am confused and really don't know on how to implement the another two points with this....

Can anyone please let me know on how to find `CPU Memory utilization`, `Memory Usage` when a python script is runned(That performs certain task) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python This might Help you

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [RunSnakeRun](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/RunSnakeRun/2.0.2b1) ([homepage](http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/)) for CPU profiling and [meliae](https://launchpad.net/meliae) for memory profiling.

I've used RunSnakeRun before and am very happy with how it performs. It even processes the cProfile dump into a visual for you so you can easily see where your code is spending most of its time.

Meliae does the same thing for memory.

As for CPU usage, you might want to just hit `top` in the commandline (assuming a linux distro) and track your process to see how much of the CPU it's hogging

Hope this helps

Comment: K thanks for reply, can u please provide me an example?, becuase all i need is when i run the python script and after execution has been completed, the total execution time,memory usage, cpu utiilization should be printed some where.....

Comment: If you look at the homepage for RunSnakeRun, you'll see examples of how it can be run. That's what I followed and it's almost too simple. Same for Meliae. As far as `top` is concerned, you need to run that command while your python script is running. While this is happening, I'm sure that you can dump it to a file as well using standard I/O redirection