# Finding Memory Usage, CPU utilization, Execution time for running a python script

Tags: python, memory, cpu-usage, execution-time

I am using python, and suppose i had some code as below

**example.py**

```
import os, psutil
import MySQLdb as mdb

conn = mdb.connect(user='root', passwd='redhat', db='File_Data', host='localhost', charset="utf8")
file_path = "/home/local/user/Module/File_processing/part-file.txt"
p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
cursor = conn.cursor()

for line in file_open:
    result = line.split('\t')
    query = "insert into PerformaceReport (campaignID, keywordID, keyword, avgPosition)"
    query += " VALUES (%s,%s,'%s',%s)%(result[0],result[1],result[2],result[3])"
    cursor.execute( query )
conn.commit()

print p.get_cpu_times()
print p.get_memory_percent()
```

The above code reads data from text file and saves to database and its working fine

I am running the file with the command `python path/to/the/example.py`

Now what i am trying to do is finding/capturing the below three values/information

1. The total `execution time` taken by the python script(`example.py`) to read and saves data to the database
2. `CPU utilization` when the python script(`example.py`) has run(executed)
3. `Memory usage` when the python script(`example.py`) has run(executed)

I already googled a lot and found some information  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938733/total-memory-used-by-python-process) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/python-memory-profiler), each explanation has different approach and i am really confused and unable to understand the approach on how to capture the above three values when the script `example.py` has run so asked in SO

Can anyone please provide me an working example(code) that suits/captures the above values for my need i mentioned above, so that i can extend further to my further needs

**Edited**

Process Followed

**1 . For finding execution time**

Run the example.py file with the command as below

```
  python -m cProfile -o file.profile example.py
```

**2 . For finding CPU Usage**

Executing the `top` command in a terminal after the example.py has runned

**Result:**

```
   PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
  1354 root      20   0  138m  17m 7200 S  2.0  0.6   2:40.50 Xorg                                             
  2672 shivakri  20   0  581m  19m  12m S  1.3  0.6   0:07.60 gnome-terminal                                   
  2587 shivakri  20   0  987m 168m  33m S  1.0  5.6   5:25.26 firefox                                          
  2780 shivakri  20   0 1233m  51m  16m S  1.0  1.7   0:16.51 gedit                                            
  2163 shivakri  20   0  821m 135m  43m S  0.7  4.5   4:58.74 chrome                                           
  1938 shivakri  20   0  567m  15m  11m S  0.3  0.5   0:06.64 metacity  
  ........
  ........
```

Now in the above result, how/where can i find the CPU/Memory utilization values, whether i need to take the values `%CPU %MEM` from the line that contains `gnome-terminal` ? (Because we are running the file through terminal ?)

Aslo `top` is used for finding total cpu utilization processes that are running, but we need to find the cpu utilization for only example.py script when it is executed/running, i mean how much CPU, Memory is utilized when we run the file(example.py)

Finally what my intention is when i run the python script (example.py) the values such as execution time,CPU utilization taken for running the script,and Memory used for running the script has to be recorded/stored some where(In to a text file) or something

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13468528/198633)

Comment: yeah i had seen that and tried like 1. "python -m cProfile example.py" then i got the execution time only, also i tried as "python -m cProfile -o OpenGLContext.profile example.py" and "python runsnake.py OpenGLContext.profile", so its also showing same only execution times

Comment: sorry for that can u provide me an example on how to implement that ?

Comment: RunSnakeRun is only for CPU profiling. Meliae is for memory profiling. And if you're on a *NIX system, `top` will give you CPU profiling

Comment: yeah but i need all these info when i run the python script example.py , how to find it ?

Comment: Look [here](http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/) for RunSnakeRun and meliae usage. Read about `top` [here](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_top.htm). If you still need help, I'll post in the morning, when I wake up. Sorry dude, but I'm ridiculously tired right now

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Yeah k i will wait for u r reply(mean while i go through that once), but don't mind please paste working code example that captures the above 3 values(it will help a lot and easy to understand the way of usage for these kind of needs). Anyway Good night Sd :)

Comment: I posted something for you. Hopefully, that should do until I wake up. Cheers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**For time profiling**

1. `cd` into the dir that contains `example.py` (lets call this `exampledir`).
2. run `python -m cProfile -o example.profile example.py`
3. [download RunSnake](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/RunSnakeRun/2.0.2b1) and unpack it anywhere
4. `cd` into the dir where you unpacked RunSnake
5. run `python runsnake.py exampledir/example.profile`

**For CPU Profiling**

1. Use [`psutil`](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation#Processes)

   1. create a new `psutil.Process` with `myProcess = psutil.Process(os.getpid())`
   2. call `myProcess.get_memory_info()` or `myProcess.get_ext_memory_info()` or `myProcess.get_memory_percent()` as required

**For memory profiling**

1. install meliae with `easy_install` or `pip`
2. Add the following lines of code to the top of `example.py`:

---

```
from meliae import scanner # [[source](http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/)]
scanner.dump_all_objects( filename ) # you can pass a file-handle if you prefer
```

---

3. run `runsnakemem fpath`, where `fpath` is the path to the file that you used in the code above.

This should get you a visual memory profiler similar to What you got with RunSnakeRun.

Hope this helps

Comment: When i tried it showing this error File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/RunSnakeRun-2.0.2b1-py2.7.egg/runsnakerun/_meliaejson.py", line 46, in loads assert source.startswith( '{' ) AssertionError

Comment: I would google that error. I've never faced that error before

Comment: run `top` WHILE `example.py` is running - not after it has finished running; and look for the `python` process in `top`

Comment: k we need to take the line that contains gnome-terminal right? and is there a way to record that in to a file, because when we execute top command,the process will not exit until we press ctrl-c or q, i tried to save like "top > some_file.txt", but the file is continously changing(processing).... My entire goal is to record those values when the python script runs

Comment: oh k how can we find python process id for that particular process, because there are many processess running, whether we need to find like "import os os.getpid()"  ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19976/discussion-between-inspectorg4dget-and-shiva-krishna)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an informative blog post if anyone still searching anything regarding this requirements:

[Monitoring memory usage of a running Python program](https://medium.com/survata-engineering-blog/monitoring-memory-usage-of-a-running-python-program-49f027e3d1ba)