# webfaction auto start mongodb

Tags: mongodb, webfaction

I read the docs on [webfaction](http://docs.webfaction.com/software/mongodb.html)
and install the mongodb with the steps

and it said :

```
To start the database, run $HOME/webapps/application/mongodb-linux-architecture-version/bin/mongod --auth --dbpath $HOME/webapps/application/data/ --port number.
To stop MongoDB while it is running in the foreground, press Ctrl + C.
```

But I need to keep the database always running
How can I do ?
Please giude me .Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Create Makefile in $HOME/webapps/

```
start:
        if ! pgrep mongod; then ./<mongodb-dir-linux-version>/bin/mongod --auth --dbpath <dbpath> --port <port> --fork --logpath ./logs/mongodb.log; fi


stop:
        pgrep mongod | xargs kill
```

Now you can easily start/stop mongodb from mongodb app directory make start/make stop and close the shh session.
Add it to cron to keep mongodb service alive even if something suddenly happens (for ex. server shutdown):

```
> export EDITOR=nano
> crontab -e
```

Add the following two lines and save.

```
*/10 * * * * make -C ~/webapps/<mongodb app name>/ -f ~/webapps/<mongodb app name>/Makefile start
@reboot make -C ~/webapps/<mongodb app name>/ -f ~/webapps/<mongodb app name>/Makefile start
```

Comment: you mean create the Makefile in $HOME/webapps/<mongodb app name>

Answer (score 0):

If you want the mongod server always up and running then you have to install it as a service. There is an installation guide in MongoDB official site:
[MongoDB Install as a Service on Linux](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

The Makefile (located under `~/webapps/mongodb`) could look as follows:

```
# Mongodb Makefile
start restart:
    ~/webapps/mongodb/mongodb-linux-x86_64-<your distribution>/bin/mongod --auth --dbpath ~/webapps/mongodb/data --port 12345 --fork --logpath ~/webapps/mongodb/logs/mongodb.log

stop:
    ~/webapps/mongodb/mongodb-linux-x86_64-<your distribution>/bin/mongod --port 12345 --dbpath ~/webapps/mongodb/data --shutdown
```

Be sure to create the logs folder in advance.

```
mkdir logs
```

@Arugin's answer does not work for multiple mongodb instances running.

Answer (score 0):

I found this works on `webfaction` for me:

In your `$HOME/webapps/mongo40` folder create a mongo_restart.sh `bash` script

```
`ps -A | grep -q '[m]ongod'`

if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
    exit 0
else
    nohup $HOME/webapps/mongo40/mongo64-rhel70/bin/mongod --auth --dbpath $HOME/webapps/mongo40/data/ --port <port number> &

exit 0
```

then, add this to your crontab with `crontab -e`:

```
@reboot nohup /home/<userfolder>/webapps/mongo40/<mongo install folder>/bin/mongod --auth --dbpath $HOME/webapps/mongo40/data/ --port <port number>
*/2 * * * * /home/<userfolder>/webapps/mongo40/mongo_restart.sh
```

That will check and reboot mongo every 2 minutes if the bash script finds it is not in memory.

Comment: A related useful trick is to add this script to your webfaction server to enable memory reporting and rebooting remotely: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603367/restart-python-py-when-it-stops-working/16625326#16625326