# Determine available memory in pure Python

Tags: python, memory, operating-system

I am aware of the [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) package which  provides (along with many other things) a way to access information about system memory, including the amount of available memory (`psutil.virtual_memory().available`). How would I go about querying available memory in a pure Python implementation? The solution would need to work for UNIX-like systems, including Linux, OS X, and so on.

Comment: You can probably read it from `/proc/meminfo`

Comment: How is the edit @BhargavRao?

Comment: @Daniel, That's a good edit, But the line *How would I go about querying available memory in a pure Python implementation?* would make it too broad. Google it, try the first one add the results to the post and it will make your post a good question. Related reads are [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already sort of answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17718729/6151889), although this method includes reading the `/proc/meminfo` file, which comes on *most* Linux/Unix distributions.

As per other operating systems, it looks like psutil is your only option, unless Windows has something similar.

**Update:**

For OS X/macOS, something similar may be possible, using `vm_stat`, like the python script in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/4296).

Comment: Windows support is not a concern, but `/proc/meminfo` is unavailable on OS X.