# How can I limit memory usage for a Python script via command line?

Tags: python

How can I limit memory usage for a Python script via command line?

For context, I'm implementing a code judge so I need to run every script students submit, I was able to do the same for Java with the following command:

```
java -Xmx<memoryLimit> Main
```

So far no luck with Python, any ideas?

PS: I'm using Python 3.8

Thank you.

Comment: Try it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41105733/limit-ram-usage-to-python-program

Comment: May be u can try `ulimit`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`ulimit`](https://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) on Linux systems. (Within Python, [there's also `resource.setrlimit()` to limit the current process.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html#resource.setrlimit))

Something like this (sorry, my Bash is rusty) should be a decent enough wrapper:

```
#!/bin/bash
ulimit -m 10240  # kilobytes
exec python3 $@
```

Then run e.g. `that-wrapper.sh student-script.py`.

(That said, are you sure you can trust your students not to submit something that uploads your secret SSH keys and/or trashes your file system? I'd suggest a stronger sandbox such as running everything in a Docker container.)

Answer (score -2):

Not sure why you want/need that. In contrast to Java, Python is very good at handling memory. It has proper garbage collectors and is quite efficient in using memory. So in my 10+ years of python programming, I never had to limit memory in python. However, if you really need it, check out this thread [Limit RAM usage to python program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41105733/limit-ram-usage-to-python-program). Someone seems to have posted a solution.

You usually limit the memory on OS level, not in python itself. You could also use Docker to achieve all of that.