# Fetch memory usage of system without using psutil

Tags: python, memory, process-monitoring

I am developing a server monitoring application. I need to get the memory usage of the system with out using the "psutil" package. Is there a way to do it in python?

Comment: Any other packages allowed? Or do you have to use onboard tools? Windows or Linux?

Comment: @Joe not supposed to use packages. i am developing for linux and windows system

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718449/determine-free-ram-in-python

Comment: Or answers in this question that use `free`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python

Comment: @Joe how to do it for windows platform?

Comment: parse out of `systeminfo` or `wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory /Value`

Comment: @Joe Do you have any example code for the same? I am new to coding.

Comment: No, but the approach is similar to the code in the links I send. You only need to adapt it slightly.