# Need to setup profiler for a multithreaded python application

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, python-3.x, profiler

I am running a multithreaded python(3.3) application which has been compiled using cx_freeze. I need to monitor the CPU usage, Memory Usage, thread info, objects info, process status.

I know there is inbuilt python profiler (cprofile) and then there is yappi and others which don't seem to serve my purpose because i want to run these profiler within my application.This way i will be able to view the profiler results and take necessary action (eg - stopping the application whenever CPU usage goes above a certain threshold)

My application is designed to run on Linux as a backgroud process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get current CPU and RAM usage in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python)

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "thread info, objects info, process status". If the above link is not enough, you should elaborate.

Comment: Yes the above solved my problem. But still not able to view the details of objects created while the application is running.