# "free command not found" while running bash script using git bash

Tags: shell, git-bash

I want to display server load, disk space, usage and memory usage in bash script.

But when I try

```
echo "Memory usage:"
memory_usage=$ free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }'
echo $memory_usage
```

this and run the script using `./test.sh` it gives me the error:

> free command not found

Comment: what do you get if you say `which free`?

Comment: To store the output of a command, say `var=$(command)`. Your `var=$ command` is wrong - note the space and the lack of parentheses around the command.

Comment: when I run script using git bash at that time I run free than also gives me error that free command not found

Comment: memory_usage=$(free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }') this is also give same error.

Comment: Well this clearly means that you don't have the `free` package installed. Check [How to add more commands to Git Bash Shell](http://superuser.com/a/701175/204979).

Answer (score 22):

for debian /ubuntu . just run

```
apt-get install procps
```

for centos

```
yum install procps
```

the procps include free , top etc linux base commond

Comment: how to install bash FREE for macOS