# How to get CPU and RAM usage from windows machine using python?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, virtual-machine, cpu-usage

In my windows machine, I have created 3 virtual machine and I want to get the CPU and RAM usage of each virtual machine using Python.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2468983/8233556

Comment: ...for anyone looking for the answer...