# Way to Access Compressed RAM (CMPRS in Top) of a Process, in macOS, via Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, memory, multiprocessing

I'm trying to figure out how to access the actual amount of RAM taken up by any given process, from Python.  I have found that psutil.Process(PID).memory_info().rss works perfectly well until the OS decides to start to compress some of a process's RAM.  Then, none of the memory_info() data seems to properly report it.  Suggestions?