# How to restart a process using python multiprocessing module

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to restart a python process using multiprocessing module,  but "AssertionError: cannot start a process twice" appears.

My question

- How can I restart the process
- Once its terminated  why it is going to zombie mod
- How can I remove the zombie process

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def worker ():
    while True:
        print "Inside the worker"
        time.sleep(10)


p1 = Process(target=worker,name="worker")
p1.start()
#p1.join()

time.sleep(3)

p1.terminate()
print "after Termination "
time.sleep(3)


p1.start()
```

Actually I am trying to create a process monitor function to watch the memory and CPU usage of all processes . If it reach a certain level I want to restart on realtime

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can I restart the process?

You cannot restart a terminated process. You need to instantiate a new process.

> Once its terminated why it is going to zombie mod?

Because on Unix-y systems the parent process needs to read the exit-code before the kernel clears the corresponding entry from the process table.

> How can I remove the zombie process?

You have multiple options. I'm citing the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#all-start-methods) here:

> Joining zombie processes
>
> On Unix when a process finishes but has not been joined it becomes a zombie. There should never be very many because each time a new process starts (or active_children() is called) all completed processes which have not yet been joined will be joined. Also calling a finished process’s Process.is_alive will join the process. Even so it is probably good practice to explicitly join all the processes that you start.

> Actually I am trying to create a process monitor function to watch the memory and CPU usage of all processes.

You should take a look at the [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module for that.

In case you just want to suspend (not kill) processes if memory consumption gets to high, you might be able to draw some inspiration from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53505397/9059420).

Answer (score 6):

I hope it will help you

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def worker ():
    while True:
        print "Inside the worker"
        time.sleep(10)

def proc_start():
    p_to_start = Process(target=worker,name="worker")
    p_to_start.start()
    return p_to_start


def proc_stop(p_to_stop):
    p_to_stop.terminate()
    print "after Termination "


p = proc_start()
time.sleep(3)
proc_stop(p)
time.sleep(3)

p = proc_start()
print "start gain"
time.sleep(3)
proc_stop(p)
```

Answer (score -2):

terminate() process will not allow to restart the process but kill() process can be used and the process can be restarted. it works

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def worker ():
    while True:
        print "Inside the worker"
        time.sleep(10)


p1 = Process(target=worker,name="worker")
p1.start()
#p1.join()

time.sleep(3)

p1.kill()
print "after kill"
time.sleep(3)


p1.start()
```

Comment: the code will raise an error assert self._popen is None, 'cannot start a process twice'