# ubuntu python3 checking RAM usage and RAM available during runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, ram

I have a python3 program that does a certain amount of iterations for a certain problem. When the problem is too complex, the program might run out of memory. **How can I check the available RAM of the hardware in python3 in order to break a cycle when reaching a certain amount of RAM usage?**

running on Ubuntu 19.04

One (not so great) way of doing this that I can think of is calling os.sytem  and scraping the RAM usage value of a command like "free".

Comment: Try this [link](https://github.com/Damodharan5/Mini_Pyth_proj/blob/master/Server_PC_Status/ram_usage.py)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python