# How to find computer specs in Python?

Tags: python, module, hardware

I am somewhat a beginner in Python, and want to make a script that would evaluate how much the users PC is worth. For this, I need to have a way to find out what the users computer specs would be.

Some things that I need to know about would be:
CPU
GPU
How much RAM
How much Storage

I have heard that there is a way to find the cpu, but how about a way to find out any of the remaining parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this question:
[How to get current CPU and RAM usage in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python)

Specs is a really general question. You're better off searching for each specific thing you want to find. I think `psutil` will give you some of what you need.