# Gekko Python3. System of equations

Tags: python-3.x, gekko

I would like to know that is the theoretical method that is behind the APM SOLVERs.

I am solving a problem where I have to solve a system of non-linear equations without any kind of constraints. I am using BPOPT solver and it works fine. 
I just would like to know what method is being used to solve such systems.  It is Newton's method? Quasi-Newtons's method?  I don't find any documentation about this.
Could you please tell me where I can find such information?

Is it also possible to know a priori the RAM that gekko solver will need to solve a system of non-linear equations with (N) variables?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is additional information on the APOPT Solver:

- Hedengren, J.D., Mojica, J.L., Cole, W., Edgar, T.F., APOPT: MINLP Solver for Differential Algebraic Systems with Benchmark Testing, INFORMS Annual Meeting, Phoenix, AZ, Oct 2012. [Presentation](https://apm.byu.edu/prism/uploads/Members/minlp_apopt_informs2012.pdf)
- [Wikipedia Article on APOPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APOPT)
- [apopt.com web-site](https://apopt.com/)
- [APMonitor Solver documentation](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmSolver)

The `BPOPT` and `IPOPT` solvers are interior point methods while the `APOPT` solver is a Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming (NLP) solver that uses an active-set SQP solver with branch and bound for integer variables.

It is difficult to know *a priori* the amount of memory that will be used. You may be able to monitor the local `apm` solve process with a tool such as `psutil` as discussed in [How to get current CPU and RAM usage in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python) There is also more information on solver methods in the [design optimization course](https://apmonitor.com/me575) and [online textbook on optimization](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/BookChapters).