# How to get CPU utilisation in python?

Tags: python, psutil

Currently i use `psutil` for getting RAM percentage

```
print ('                                                                   ')
print ('----------------------CPU Information summary----------------------')
print ('                                                                   ')

# gives a single float value
vcc=psutil.cpu_count()
print ('Total number of CPUs :',vcc)

vcpu=psutil.cpu_percent()
print ('Total CPUs utilized percentage :',vcpu,'%')
```

But when I run the code i get this

```
----------------------CPU Information summary----------------------

Total number of CPUs : 8

Total CPUs utilized percentage : 0.0 %
```

But i want it print the CPU % in task manager

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current CPU and RAM usage in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python)

Comment: nope i tried it it give cpu usage is 0.0% .I want to know if this should be used in a different way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the documentation:

**psutil.cpu_percent(interval=None, percpu=False)**

> Return a float representing the current system-wide CPU utilization as a percentage. When interval is > 0.0 compares system CPU times elapsed before and after the interval (blocking). When interval is 0.0 or None compares system CPU times elapsed since last call or module import, returning immediately. That means the first time this is called it will return a **meaningless 0.0 value which you are supposed to ignore**. In this case it is recommended for accuracy that **this function be called with at least 0.1 seconds between calls**. When percpu is True returns a list of floats representing the utilization as a percentage for each CPU. First element of the list refers to first CPU, second element to second CPU and so on. The order of the list is consistent across calls.

So it needs to be called with an interval between calls so it can give the right percentage.

Called it like this (or try to play around with the interval parameter):

```
psutil.cpu_percent(interval=2)
```

Comment: this thing give me value after two secs though i want it to be like the taskmgr one

Comment: you need to play around a little bit with the values. Have you tried passing 0.1 ?

Comment: hmm yeah .. .  .