# how to get the average CPU usage of GCP instance per day via python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm looking for how can I get GCE instance average CPU usage per day using stackdriver python libraries.

I can see per interval series but per day in google docs.

Comment: Here is a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2468983/10415226) which have a good answer, this could be helpful.

Comment: @shamma i need CPU usage by stackdriver(monitoring) python libraries

Comment: If you can get per interval, you can set a day interval and get the value of the day no?

Comment: How to get that?! @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: Check this https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-collect-gce-metrics/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
curl \
  'https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/timeSeries?aggregation.alignmentPeriod=86400s&aggregation.perSeriesAligner=ALIGN_MEAN&filter=metric.type%3D%22compute.googleapis.com%2Finstance%2Fcpu%2Fusage_time%22%20AND%20metric.labels.instance_name%3D%22YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME%22&interval.endTime=2020-10-03T00%3A00%3A00Z&interval.startTime=2020-10-01T00%3A00%3A00Z' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

With precision:

- Replace YOUR_PROJECT_ID by your project ID
- Replace YTOUR_INSTANCE_NAME by the instance that you want to observe
- Change your interval.startTime and interval.endTime to match the interval that you want to observe
- aggregation.alignmentPeriod=86400 means that I ask for a value aggregation per day. But how?? (line below)
- aggregation.perSeriesAligner=ALIGN_MEAN means that I perform a MEAN for the aggregation.

Therefore, I take the CPU usage of my VM, and I ask a MEAN aggregation every 86400s (every day).