# How to get GCP vm instance total memory size using python?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-api-python-client

I want to run python startup script inside gcp instance in which i want to get total memory size of gcp instance.

I have tried `free -h` , `grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo` commands. But, the problem with this commands is, i get some less amount of RAM than actual memory size i selected while creating instance (due to system use may be). I want to get the exact memory size i selected while creating instance.
*e.g., "32 GB" for "e2-standard-8" , "16 GB" for "n2-standard-4*

Also there is no metadata url available to get gcp instance memory size.

Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Please share your python script so we can view what you have tried. Also, where are you executing the script, in the VM or outside GCP?

Comment: I am executing the script inside vm. 

I am using below function in python to get memory size:

import psutil
psutil.virtual_memory().total



I have tried free -h command also.

Comment: I found this [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2468983/11198184) regarding to get current CPU and RAM usage in Python. This might be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the RAM as configured when you created the VM in GCP, I think using the [Compute Engine Libs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/libraries) would be useful.

First intall the needed libs:

```
pip install google-api-python-client
```

If you need it for just one instance this can be helpful:

```py
import googleapiclient.discovery

PROJECT_ID="project_id"
ZONE="zone_where_the_instance_is"

compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
instances = compute.instances().list(project=PROJECT_ID, zone=ZONE).execute()
for instance in instances['items']:
    ram = compute.machineTypes().get(project=PROJECT_ID, zone=ZONE, machineType=instance['machineType'].rsplit('/', 1)[-1]).execute()['memoryMb']
    print ("RAM -> {:.1f} GB".format(round(ram/1024,1)))
```

And you'll get:

```
RAM -> 1.8 GB
```

A more general approach to get this info from all the instances in a project could be as follows:

First add this additional lib:

```
pip install tabulate
```

Then:

```py
import googleapiclient.discovery
from tabulate import tabulate

PROJECT_ID="project_id"

compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
zones = compute.zones().list(project=PROJECT_ID).execute()
configs=[]
for zone in zones['items']: 
    instances = compute.instances().list(project=PROJECT_ID, zone=zone['name']).execute()
    if 'items' in instances:
        for instance in instances['items']:
            ram = compute.machineTypes().get(project=PROJECT_ID, zone=zone['name'], machineType=instance['machineType'].rsplit('/', 1)[-1]).execute()['memoryMb']
            configs.append([instance['name'],str(round(ram/1024,1))+" GB"])
print(tabulate(configs, headers=["Instance name", "RAM"]))
```

Which will print something like this:

```
Instance name    RAM
---------------  ------
satellite        1.8 GB
```

Those scripts asume you've configured previously the credentials for Cloud SDK.

Comment: It solved my issue, Thanks :)

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the same thing in aws?

Comment: I would suggest creating a new question for that.

Comment: Sure @YeriPelona