# monitoring Ram usage and trigger , python flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm a beginner at flask.
I want to implement a function that runs when RAM usage exceeds 80 percent on my server.
What is the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

you can import psutil to check the memory.

memory_usage = psutil.virtual_memory().percent

you can check the link to have more ideas about it.
https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I wish if my answer is good.

Answer (score 0):

Reading how much ram is used is very simple, as you can also read from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python) always asked on stackoverflow:

```
import psutil
# you can calculate percentage of available memory
print(str(psutil.virtual_memory().available * 100 / psutil.virtual_memory().total))
20.8
```

To install psutil:

```
pip install psutil
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey this works `psutil` to get the ram usage like this. But if you are calling a different function from a library during the route, if the memory usage spikes it fails to catch. While you can record before and after usage for a process id.

```py
import psutil

def your_route_handler():
    process = psutil.Process() #initiate only once
    memory_info = process.memory_info()
    rss = memory_info.rss
    rss_mb = rss / (1024 * 1024)
    print(f"Memory usage: {rss_mb} MB")

    # Your route logic here...
```