# Get process CPU usage in percentage in python

Tags: python, process, cpu-usage, percentage

I'm making an destktop application like task manager. How to get the specific cpu usage of google.exe?

Comment: Already answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python

Comment: [`psutil`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.cpu_percent) should be used for this.

Comment: I want to get specific process usage in percentage ,for example chrome.exe : %25 steam.exe : %15 .......

Comment: I tried the psutil library but i got total cpu usage.I want to get specific process usage in percentage .Thank you for the answer @CoderCharmander

Comment: As in @Eugenij's answer, you can use individual process objects to get their CPU usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [psutil library](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.cpu_percent) for your task

```
pip install psutil
```

Usage:

```
import psutil

chrome = None
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == "chrome.exe":
        chrome = proc
        print(chrome.cpu_percent())
```

Comment: output : 0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0  Does not seem to get percentage properly on windows.

Comment: @Burak Try to set interval: `print(chrome.cpu_percent(interval=0.1))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
import psutil

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == 'chrome.exe':
        try:
            pinfo = proc.as_dict(attrs=['pid'])
        except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
            pass
        else:
            print(pinfo['pid'])
            p = psutil.Process(pinfo['pid'])
            print(p.cpu_percent(1))
```

But you should count sum of this process