# How to measure execution stats of a Python script CPU usage, RAM usage, disk usage etc?

Tags: python

Is there a Python module that you can use to get execution stats for a piece of code or a python app ? For example something like:

```
get_stats.start() 
#python code 
stats = get_stats.end()
```

The stats I am interested in are cpu usage, ram usage and execution time

Comment: You could look into [profilers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html)

Comment: For execution time you can use the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html), for CPU/RAM usage I'd use an external program (e.g. Windows Task Manager, UNIX htop).

Comment: @jfaccioni I wish to avoid using an external program and just get the stats from the script itself

Comment: @Tobi208 hey. Thanks from what I see profilers only give time statistics right? No cpu or ram

Comment: How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python)

Comment: @Tobi208 yeah I ve seen it than you. I a using this at the moment to make my own solution based on this tool. But there is nothing ready made at the moment it seems which is weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So using [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) i made this helper metrics class you can see in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kziovas/e1688a21367f3ed9676c3e2697f45924)