# How to get a report from CPU and RAM usage of a specific user in a period of time using Python?

Tags: python, ubuntu, monitoring, cpu-usage, ram

Is there a Python module to get a report from CPU and RAM usage of a specific user of an Ubuntu system between two dates? If there is no such a tool, I wonder how can I implement such an application using pure Python code? What is the starting point for doing that?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python) seems to address the way of obtaining current CPU and RAM usage. What I need is to get a history of CPU (for example, in terms of the number of clocks) and RAM (in terms of bytes) usage for each user between two given dates. Are these information logged and stored by Linux? If yes, where are they stored? If not, how can I implement such a monitoring tool in Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current CPU and RAM usage in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python)

Comment: Thanks @SembeiNorimaki as far as I understand this answer addresses the way to obtain current CPU and RAM usage. What I need is to obtain usage history for each user. My question is, are such information logged by Linux? If not, how can I implement such a monitoring tool in Python?