# How to get RAM usage (total, used, free, free/total, used/total) in R?

Tags: r

How can I get the current RAM usage  in R? Ideally, it would work for both Unix and Windows platforms. In windows I used following code:

```
total_mem<-system("wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory", intern = TRUE)
total_mem<-as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", total_mem[2]))
total_mem<-total_mem/1000
free_mem<-system("wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory", intern = TRUE)
free_mem<-as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", free_mem[2]))
used_mem<-total_mem-free_mem
percentage_used_mem<-1-free_mem/total_mem
```

Is there a better way to get the current RAM usage, such that works with both Unix and Windows platforms.

According to [how to get current cpu and ram usage in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python) and the "reticulate" package:

```
library(reticulate)
aa<-reticulate::import("psutil")
mem_percent=aa$virtual_memory()$percent
```

But this way needs Python to be installed on the platform.

Comment: are you looking for the garbage cleaner `gc()`?

Comment: @D.J, Can I get the current RAM usage(total, percent) with gc()?

Comment: i don't think so - i thought you wanted to know R's ram useage. there is a way to [check](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/1500005616261-Understanding-Memory-Usage-in-the-RStudio-IDE) with rstudio (total ram) but i don't know how to replicate it