# How to monitor memory usage using Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process?

Tags: python, windows, memory, wmi

I have a windows 10 PC on the shop floor of a 24/7 manufacturing plant. The PC runs fine if its memory usage is around 25 or 30% like it is after a restart. If it gets up over about 85%, applications will have errors or unexpectedly close. I do not have admin rights on this PC and new software isn't really an option because of a difficult approval process, so I want to stick with WMI. I'm using the `Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process` class to log the individual processes but I'm not sure which class properties most closely follow "Memory %" in Task Manager/Performance/Memory.

My data logger is in Python. I have it running every hour and saving Name and IDProcess for all processes. What other properties should I save? What will these additional properties tell me? Should I be using `Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process` instead?

Comment: Was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python not useful?